# ag-grid context menu is cut off (clipped)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Having a ag-grid (Angular component) of ag-grid v8.20
Unfortunately the context menu is clipped if it is bigger than the grid:

(screenshot should be here but I can't upload it, imgur bug?)

Is there a way to make the context menu display completely, without clipping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was clipped because of a CSS style I set on my component.
In my case it was a flexbox with "overflow-y: auto".
I had to remove that to make it work.

Comment: You mean ".ag-body-viewport.ag-layout-normal". NO, not working.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone else comes across this post, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QaWPuLsThnp1J0zA9Yds?p=preview) is a plunker to demonstrate the fix.

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    popupParent: document.querySelector("body")
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a general answer for people facing the same issue in react and typescript. This works for me.

`popupParent={document.querySelector('body') || undefined}`